# need help on nginx configuration for nodejs api

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx, directory, reverse-proxy

my node api starts on port 1337 and works fine. if I browse `localhost:1337` my api return `nothing` and if I browse `localhost:1337/products` my api actually works fine and return my products list as Json.
now service nginx installed and configured well to reverse-proxy of `localhost:1337` to `localhost`
so after opening `localhost` it somehow works and says `nothing` as before but if I try browsing `localhost/products` again says `nothing`
and don't care about `products`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have found the issue.
in nginx default configuration removed everything in section `location /api/` just copy `proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;` lonely. and it works correctly.